# How to dynamically add jobs to a Scrapy/Selenium spider?

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy + Selenium to scrape Facebook friends data. I want to write a program that would take 2 usernames as input, recursively scrape their friendlists until a chain that connects the 2 users is found. My spider can login, generate Items and send them to MongoDB (through a Pipeline). I have a working function that can make a query to Mongo to check if a chain exists and return it. My take on the algorithm:

1. Get input (2 usernames)
2. Put the 2 users into crawling QUEUE
3. Facebook login
4. Pop the QUEUE and start crawling
5. Once every other Item is sent to Mongo -> check if chain is found -> if not: put scraped user's friends usernames into the QUEUE -> pop the QUEUE.
6. Once chain is found -> Crawl + write new chains(if found) and pop until QUEUE is empty
7. Return all found chains

The login process is just a function that creates a Selenium instance, successfully logins and returns the webdriver instance, that is further passed into the spider.

At the moment I can't understand how to organise the QUEUE process. I can pass a single username or a list into the spider, but can't figure out how to pass more jobs into the same spider depending on the results of the crawling.

I start the crawl for a single user as follows:

```
process = CrawlerProcess(config)
process.crawl(FacebookSpider, <username>, session)
process.start()
```

How would I go about adding new usernames to the QUEUE (right after one crawl is finished and the Item is processed) without stopping the spider? Or maybe the approach should be 'wait for spider to finish job'->'create new one'?

I've tried digging through the Scrapy documentation, but for a newbie like me it was overwhelming. I tried to use CrawlerRunner, but couldn't get it to to work.

Comment: wouldn't you just `yield process.crawl(args)` ?

Comment: That's the CrawlerRunner approach, right? How does that work? I tried using all of the examples from 'Common practices', but couldn't start a single spider job.

Comment: what would yield process.crawl? would it be a separate method within the spider class?